# Selected item in drop down menu changes depending on page

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu

I am working on my html page with adds. In my code I have a drop down menu, in which you can select order of adds. I want to change the selected item in drop down menu depending on which order was selected by user (and was redirected to same site, only order is different). How can I do that? Whit JS code?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with js code

Answer (score 0):

```js
 /*! Select2 4.0.5 | https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/LICENSE.md */
 
 $(function () {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('.select2').select2()
```

```html
<select class="select2" >
 <option>1</option>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>1</option>
 </select>
```